# MacOS Server - включить файловый сервер

Tags: сервер, macos, ftp, mac, smb

Настраиваю сервер на основе Mac Pro на операционной системе MacOS Server Snow Leopard. Мне нужно настроить файловый сервер.

У меня отсутствует пункт File Sharing в меню Sharing.
[image: у меня]
Раньше он у меня был, но переустанавливал ОС. Раньше у меня выглядело меню как на данной картинке:
[image: вот так должно]

Как исправить данную проблему? Можно ли как-то по другому настроить файловый сервер?

Comment: А можно полюбопытствовать, с чем связана необходимость использовать настолько устаревшую версию macOS?

Comment: @andreymal версия не имеет значение, ведь раньше на этой версии всё работало. Фирма начинающая и купила мак 2014 года. И это не имеет отношение к вопросу.